# C# validate XML file using XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

[I have a XML file](http://pastebin.com/1nDYHe8V) - its generated from parser [here](https://github.com/konraddroptable/XML_Parser/tree/master/XMLParser) and [I have a XSD file](http://pastebin.com/CXmZj0vQ) . The key is to validate the XML file (from specific path) using the XSD file (from specific path) and return flag if it's validated or not. Most of the code I saw was without using a XSD file to validate. Is there a possible way to validate XML file using XSD **file**?

Comment: Ok, how to do it without a targetNamespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument() ;
doc.load(xmlFileName) ;
doc.Schemas.Add("",xsdFileName);
doc.Schemas.Compile();
TheSchemaErrors   = new List<string>() ;
TheSchemaWarnings = new List<string>() ;
doc.Validate(Xml_ValidationEventHandler);
if (TheSchemaErrors  .Count>0) { // display errors  }
if (TheSchemaWarnings.Count>0) { // display warnings  }
...
private List<string> TheSchemaErrors ;
private List<string> TheSchemaWarnings ;

private void Xml_ValidationEventHandler(object sender,ValidationEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Severity)
  {
    case XmlSeverityType.Error   : TheSchemaErrors  .Add(e.Message) ; break;
    case XmlSeverityType.Warning : TheSchemaWarnings.Add(e.Message) ; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer as you just did a code dump without any explanation of what's happening. The least you can do is comment the code and mention relevant classes.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for couple hours

Comment: @Reticulated Spline: Your remark is generally true. But In this case, code is self-explanatory : I extracted some code of one of my applications and refactored it to be readable. If a clarification was required on any part of this code, a lot of people in the forum could respond.